# Permission error when trying to access Report Manager URL unless UAC is disabled

Tags: reporting-services, uac, permission-denied, configurationmanager, reportmanager

I get a permission error when trying to access the Report Manager URL in the browser if UAC is enabled.

I know from reading other posts that UAC needs to be disabled to allow this to work and that works for me as well.

My concern now is when I install SQL Server with Reporting Services on the user computer I will also have to disable UAC.

Is there any way to get it to work and also have UAC enabled at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If UAC is enabled, you can launch IE with the "Run as Administrator" context menu option and you then you can access Report Manager on the local machine. (Right click on IE in the start menu, select "Run as administrator." Then you will need to approve the UAC prompt as IE launches.)